# How to send mail in php using mailgun API

Tags: php, mailgun

I am using Mailgun first time for sending the mail to the user.

I am using below mail for testing

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = Mailgun::create('api key', 'https://API_HOSTNAME');
$domain = "mydomain.com";
$params = array(
  'from'    => 'sender@mydomain.com', // this is registered email address
  'to'      => 'receiver@gmail.com',
  'subject' => 'Hello',
  'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
);

# Make the call to the client.
$mg->messages()->send($domain, $params);
?>
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^3.0",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
        "php-http/message": "^1.8"
    }
}
```

Now when I run my page then I am getting below error. I added my domain, TXT, MX on GoDaddy.

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Http\Discovery\Exception\DiscoveryFailedException: Could not find
>   resource using any discovery strategy. Find more information at
>   http://docs.php-http.org/en/latest/discovery.html#common-errors - Puli
>   Factory is not available - No valid candidate found using strategy
>   "Http\Discovery\Strategy\CommonClassesStrategy". We tested the
>   following candidates: . - No valid candidate found using strategy
>   "Http\Discovery\Strategy\CommonPsr17ClassesStrategy". We tested the
>   following candidates: Nyholm\Psr7\Factory\Psr17Factory,
>   Zend\Diactoros\UriFactory, Http\Factory\Diactoros\UriFactory,
>   Http\Factory\Guzzle\UriFactory, Http\Factory\Slim\UriFactory. in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailgun-php/vendor/php-http/discovery/src/Exception/DiscoveryFailedException.php:41
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailgun-php/vendor/php-http/discovery/src/ClassDiscovery.php(79):
>   Http\Discovery\Exception\DiscoveryFailedException::create(Array) #1
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailgun-php/vendor/php-http/discovery/src/Psr17FactoryDiscovery.php(117):
>   in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailgun-php/vendor/php-http/discovery/src/Psr17FactoryDiscovery.php
>   on line 22

Would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: hey where you able to solve it? Im having the exact same problem

Comment: @bermick, No, Even I want to know the answer.

Comment: what are your versions? Im using laravel 5, php 7 and mailgun 3

Comment: @bermick, I am using php7 and mailgun latest one.

Comment: i ended moving to sendgrid because i needed that solved asap

Comment: @bermick, Yes SendGrid is good. I also suggest you to use that instated of mailgun

Answer (score 2):

from mailgun's github repo, https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php#installation

`If you just want to get started quickly you should run the following command:`

```
composer require mailgun/mailgun-php kriswallsmith/buzz nyholm/psr7
```

run the above composer instruction and the error should be gone

i had the same issue, and that solved it for me, that is provided your are doing everything else right(apikey, hostname and domain)

if you still get stuck, then just follow the remaining instruction in the GitHub repo